# WPF - Making ONE control stretch vertically

Tags: wpf, xaml, autolayout, autoresize, window-resize

I'm new to WPF/XAML and with a few hours I got a GUI that is presentable except for one thing. I got the controls to resize horizontally with the window but I cannot figure out what I'm missing to do the same vertically. I want only the DataGrid control to stretch vertically. The Datagrid control is not getting the hint. What am I missing?

```
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
MinHeight="480"
MinWidth="660"
Width="660"
Height="480"
Title="Windows Title">
<Grid Margin="0,0,-0.2,0.2">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            Width="Auto"
            Height="Auto"
            MinHeight="300"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox
        x:Name="Interpretation"
            Height="100"
            MinHeight="100"
            Width="Auto"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="Interpretation of Results"
            TextAlignment="left"
            TextBlock.FontSize="20"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

**SOLUTION with ADDED controls and comments**

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Height="600"
    MinHeight="600"
    MinWidth="660"
    Width="660"
    Title="Windows Title">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!--                    Height="Auto" -> Fill space required by content -->
    <!--                    Height="*" -> Fill all space not taken up by other rows (The one that will stretch) -->
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <!-- using HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" or Width="Auto" in the controls is redundant -->
    <!-- Don't forget to add Grid.Row="#" properties in each control/row below -->
        <TextBox
            MinHeight="25"
            Grid.Row="0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            Background="#FF98D6EB"
            Foreground="White"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="Results"
            TextAlignment="Center"
            TextBlock.FontSize="20"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <DataGrid
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            MinHeight="200"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            TextBlock.FontSize="16"/>
        <TextBox
            x:Name="Interpretation"
            MinHeight="100"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            Background="#FF98D6EB"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="Interpretation of Results"
            TextAlignment="left"
            TextBlock.FontSize="20"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
    <!-- UniformGrid speads the buttons size evenly with resizing of the window -->
    <!-- HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" is redundant -->
    <!-- notice the Grid.Row="3" is a property of <UniformGrid> and not the controls within it-->
        <UniformGrid
            Height="100"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Columns="2"
            Rows="1">
            <Button
                Name="btnContinue"
                MinWidth="250"
                Margin="10"
                Content="Continue"
                TextBlock.FontSize="50"
                TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Button
                Name="btnCancel"
                MinWidth="250"
                Margin="10"
                Content="Cancel"
                TextBlock.FontSize="50"
                TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Grid will expand to fill its parent. You can use the root level grid in your window, if you won't be adding any more content.

To put two controls in a grid one above the other, define rows, and don't neglect to add the `Grid.Row="..."` attribute to the child controls to determine which grid rows they'll be in, or else they'll be superimposed on one another.

```
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-0.2,0.2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!-- Height="*" -> Fill all space not taken up by other rows -->
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <!-- Height="Auto" -> Fill space required by content -->
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="dataGrid"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            TextBlock.FontSize="16"
            />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Row="1"
            x:Name="Interpretation"
            Height="100"
            MinHeight="100"
            Margin="10,10,10,0"
            IsReadOnly="True"
            Text="Interpretation of Results"
            TextAlignment="left"
            TextBlock.FontSize="20"
            TextWrapping="Wrap"
            />
    </Grid>
```

If you've got a series of auto-sized children that'll be adjacent, it can be simpler to make one row a StackPanel:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <DataGrid 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        ... 
        />

    <StackPanel 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Orientation="Vertical"
        >
        <Label>Stuff</Label>
        <TextBox ... />
        <Label>More Stuff</Label>
        <TextBox ... />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: While this does work for 2 controls, when I add other controls before or after these 2 controls they don't stack; they pile on top of each other. And this is with adding <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> lines for each control.

Comment: @Mr.Annoyed So you add a third grid row, you put `Grid.Row="2"` on the new control, and it gets superimposed on another control? I've never seen that.

Comment: I didn't notice the Grid.Row="#" property. Now it makes sense and works

Comment: @Mr.Annoyed Ahh, OK. Yeah, most grids (e.g. HTML) don't work that way.

Comment: @Mr.Annoyed If you have a bunch of adjacent auto-sized child controls, you can put them in a StackPanel and make the StackPanel the second row of the grid. Lots of ways to combine layout controls.

Comment: Grid layout is the reason I liked working with WPF/Silverlight - it's 1000 times more intuitive than HTML's completely mental layout model...

Answer (score 1):

You put it in a stackpanel.

Stackpanels only ever grow to the size their contents need, you should use Grid instead, grids and their cells will fill their container.